# Recursively move and rename into one directory

Tags: bash

I have multiple directories with jpg's inside of them and i'd like to move them all to one main directory and rename them all numerically.

I tried

```sh
export i=1
find /a -name '*.jpg' -exec cp {} /b/"${i}".jpg \; -exec export i=((i++)) \;
```

and

```
export i=1
for file in /a/*.jpg; do cp "$file" "/b/${i}.jpg"; ((i++)); done;
```

But both of them don't work how i want them to, any help appreciated.

Comment: The first one runs `cp ... /b/1.jpg` for each file found; even if `i` were incremented in the shell that runs `find` (it's not; it's incremented in a subprocess that exits immediately), the new values of `i` aren't used. I don't seen any glaring problems with the second one; what does it do instead?

Comment: (The second one isn't recursive at all, if that's the issue. You might want `shopt -s globstar; for file in /a/**/*.jpg; do ...; done` instead.)

Comment: `for file in /a/**/*.jpg; do cp "$file" "/b/${i}.jpg"; ((i++)) done` worked for me @chepner

Comment: Side note: The purpose of the `export` keyword is not to define a variable. If you want a variable i containing 1, just write `i=1` (or, strictly equivalent, `i="1"`)

Comment: Also, be careful with glob patterns: `/a/**/*.jpg` is not equivalent to `find /a/ -type f -name '*.jpg'` but `find -L /a/ -name '*.jpg'`. With glob patterns, you will have duplicate files for each path traversing a symbolic link.